# Selenium doesnt capture entire responce body using python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, deployment

So i am trying to capture the responce of a body of  website and i was able to do it previously but all of a sudden only half of the responce is visible and some part of the responce bosy is missing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import math
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from seleniumwire.utils import decode
import re
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from flask import Flask, jsonify ,redirect,url_for,render_template,request,json
from datetime import datetime
import gzip
import io

username = "VU21CSEN0100120"
password = "password@123"
options = Options()

options.add_argument("--headless=new")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://newgstudent.gitam.edu/Home/GetAttendancedatachart?category=subject")
username_textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtusername")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)


password_textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID,"password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)


login_button = driver.find_element(By.ID,"Submit")
login_button.click()

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Attendance'))
)
button.click()

#for matching subject to subject code
driver.get("https://newgstudent.gitam.edu/Home/GetAttendancedatachart?category=subject")
for requests in driver.requests:
    if requests.url == "https://newgstudent.gitam.edu/Home/GetAttendancedatachart?category=subject":
        responce=requests.response
        de2=decode(responce.body,responce.headers.get('Content-Encoding','identity'))
        debody2=de2.decode("utf-8")


html_code = debody2
pattern = re.compile(r'<td\s.*?>(.*?)</td>|<td>(.*?)</td>')
matches = pattern.findall(html_code)
extracted_text2 = []
for match in matches:
    for group in match:
        if group:
            extracted_text2.append(group)
extracted_data2 = []

for text in extracted_text2:
    if text.startswith("<"):
        input_string = text
        pattern = re.compile(r'value\s*=\s*["\'](.*?)["\']')
        match = pattern.search(input_string)
        if match:
            value = match.group(1)
        else:
            extracted_data2.append("No match found")
    else:
        extracted_data2.append(text)
k=1
subcodematcher={}
matcherstore=""
for i in extracted_data2:
    if(k%2!=0):
        subcodematcher[i]=""
        matcherstore=i
    else:
        subcodematcher.update({matcherstore:i})
    k=k+1
# print(subcodematcher)
        
    
driver.get("https://newgstudent.gitam.edu/Home/GetAttendancedata?category=Custom%20Range&date=28-11-2023%20to%2029-12-2023")
for requests in driver.requests:
    if requests.url == "https://newgstudent.gitam.edu/Home/GetAttendancedata?category=Custom%20Range&date=28-11-2023%20to%2029-12-2023":
        responce=requests.response
        de=decode(responce.body,responce.headers.get('Content-Encoding','identity'))
        debody=de.decode("utf-8")
print(debody)
```

I tried differet ways but nothing seems to solve it using but it never seems to get the complete responce body

```
    
driver.get("https://newgstudent.gitam.edu/Home/GetAttendancedata?category=Custom%20Range&date=28-11-2023%20to%2029-12-2023")
for requests in driver.requests:
    if requests.url == "https://newgstudent.gitam.edu/Home/GetAttendancedata?category=Custom%20Range&date=28-11-2023%20to%2029-12-2023":
        responce=requests.response
        de=decode(responce.body,responce.headers.get('Content-Encoding','identity'))
        debody=de.decode("utf-8")
```